# Editing CSS real time with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm looking for an extension or tool that will enable me to edit CSS real time from the browser. I installed Stylebot which works well but whenever I save the new CSS, it only retains the stylesheet in the browser and not the CSS file or HTML file. I can't figure out how to make changes to the CSS file itself, and I'm not sure that's even a possibility with Stylebot.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: While addressing editing Sass, [you might find this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192746/compass-sass-and-web-developer-extension/14995255#14995255) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works for me http://tin.cr/
its really nice and as simple as installing the extension. 
Happy coding :)

any changes you make are already added to the css file. kind of like an inverse livereload :)